# json.parse fails on unexpected token, when other parsers say it is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi I am trying to convert a data to json in javascript using

```
Json.parse(data);
```

and it keeps on saying

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 

at Object.parse (native)
at new t (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js:2:14070), <anonymous>:1:54784)
at Object.e [as invoke] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:36:315)
at $get.w.instance (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:75:451)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:58:476
at s (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:7:408)
at A (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:58:459)
at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:51:299)
at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:51:316)
at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:51:316)
```

I am guessing that it is saying that there is a space somewhere, however I used a bunch of parser tools online and it said that the json is valid. Is there a more reliable Json parser that i can use in javascript or how can I make sure that my data is parsable

Here is the string I am trying to convert

```
[{"SessionToken":null,"ErrorMessage":null,"BusinessId":0,"CustomerId":0,"Name":null,"EMail":"","ContactId":"","KeyValueTags":null,"AccountId":"","FirstClickId":0,"LastClickId":0,"SFServerName":"","LeadId_Current":null,"Lead_Type":0,"TotalForms":1,"TotalSessions":2,"TotalCustomEvents":0,"TotalABTests":0,"PageViews":5,"LastVisit":"2015-03-29T07:44:17Z","TimeZoneOffset":"16:00:00","SessionsData":[{"WebSource":"Google AdWords","ReferralId":0,"SessionId":0,"UserId":"","Email":"","ContactUrl":null,"SessionDate":"2015-03-29T07:15:14Z","ClickType":"LC","ABTests":[],"CustomEvents":[],"HasForm":false,"Events":[{"EventType":"PageView","EventSource":"","EventTime":"2015-03-29T07:15:14Z","GMT_EventTime":"2015-03-29T07:15:14Z","PageUrl":"http://www.mycase.com/legal-practice-management-software?_bt=42684442540&_bk=%2bmy+%2bcase&_bm=b&gclid=CJf-...eView","EventSource":"","EventTime":"2015-03-29T07:11:30Z","GMT_EventTime":"2015-03-29T07:11:30Z","PageUrl":"http://www.mycase.com/legal-practice-management-software?_bt=42684442540&_bk=%2bmy+%2bcase&_bm=b&gclid=CJf-nJOBzcQCFYRCaQodro4Akw","PageTitle":"MyCase | Legal Practice Management Software","ReferrerUrl":"http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=C2hcjjaUXVZaGKemLsAf4zIDwBbyXlZpBnIqW4p4B-7vf3p4BCAAQASCjn9UmYMnOq4j0o7QSoAHs1tXTA8gBAaoEKk_QBDZzCtwBsfQY3U_e_qDQKNtnQiD2MOh6BXZjEPh9kHPb2HWDq_TA54AFs_j-GIgGAdgGBIAH_KiqLJAHA6gHpr4b2AcB&ohost=www.google.com&cid=5GhDCu-n2kqN4eYWZsysECDFS4D7Gd5wpxhcethUGY2l-qg&sig=AOD64_2xEQSmG4Lgj7Tux2Hszj5yu5WNZA&rct=j&q=&ved=0CCAQ0Qw&adurl=http://www.mycase.com/legal-practice-management-software%3F_bt%3D42684442540%26_bk%3D%252Bmy%2520%252Bcase%26_bm%3Db"}],"Device":{"BrowserInfo":{"Name":"Chrome","Version":"30.0"},"PlatformInfo":{"Name":"Android","Version":"4.4"}},"IPInfo":null}],"Cookies":[""],"Hosts":null}]
```

Comment: Are you sure you're passing a string into JSON.parse? The object you provided pasted is already a legitimate JavaScript object, not a string.

Comment: can you `console.log(typeof data);` to see if it an object or a string you are passing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is already an object of type Array. To access the Object:

```
var foo = data[0];

alert(foo.SessionToken); //for example..
```

JSON.parse takes a String and parses it into an equivalent JavaScript value.

Comment: thanks for the response. Sorry I wasnt clear. The value I had before was the converted json for an online json parser (not Json.parse). I posted the actual string I am trying to convert

Comment: Can you try : `Json.parse(JSON.stringify(data[0])); ` ?

Comment: just made it back to a string again :(

Comment: What made it to string? `json.stringify`? that's the purpose of doing so!

Comment: if you are sure `data` is a string, you can try to remove `[` and `]` from the beginning and end of `data` and then parse again.

Comment: That worked. Thanks for the help. Do you know how to parse arrays?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `JSON.parse` expects a JSON object, not a JSON array. The workaround is to wrap the array in an object:

```
var rawData = '[{"SessionToken":null,"ErrorMessage":null,"BusinessId":0,"CustomerId":0,"Name":null,"EMail":"","ContactId":"","KeyValueTags":null,"AccountId":"","FirstClickId":0,"LastClickId":0,"SFServerName":"","LeadId_Current":null,"Lead_Type":0,"TotalForms":1,"TotalSessions":2,"TotalCustomEvents":0,"TotalABTests":0,"PageViews":5,"LastVisit":"2015-03-29T07:44:17Z","TimeZoneOffset":"16:00:00","SessionsData":[{"WebSource":"Google AdWords","ReferralId":0,"SessionId":0,"UserId":"","Email":"","ContactUrl":null,"SessionDate":"2015-03-29T07:15:14Z","ClickType":"LC","ABTests":[],"CustomEvents":[],"HasForm":false,"Events":[{"EventType":"PageView","EventSource":"","EventTime":"2015-03-29T07:15:14Z","GMT_EventTime":"2015-03-29T07:15:14Z","PageUrl":"http://www.mycase.com/legal-practice-management-software?_bt=42684442540&_bk=%2bmy+%2bcase&_bm=b&gclid=CJf-...eView","EventSource":"","EventTime":"2015-03-29T07:11:30Z","GMT_EventTime":"2015-03-29T07:11:30Z","PageUrl":"http://www.mycase.com/legal-practice-management-software?_bt=42684442540&_bk=%2bmy+%2bcase&_bm=b&gclid=CJf-nJOBzcQCFYRCaQodro4Akw","PageTitle":"MyCase | Legal Practice Management Software","ReferrerUrl":"http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=C2hcjjaUXVZaGKemLsAf4zIDwBbyXlZpBnIqW4p4B-7vf3p4BCAAQASCjn9UmYMnOq4j0o7QSoAHs1tXTA8gBAaoEKk_QBDZzCtwBsfQY3U_e_qDQKNtnQiD2MOh6BXZjEPh9kHPb2HWDq_TA54AFs_j-GIgGAdgGBIAH_KiqLJAHA6gHpr4b2AcB&ohost=www.google.com&cid=5GhDCu-n2kqN4eYWZsysECDFS4D7Gd5wpxhcethUGY2l-qg&sig=AOD64_2xEQSmG4Lgj7Tux2Hszj5yu5WNZA&rct=j&q=&ved=0CCAQ0Qw&adurl=http://www.mycase.com/legal-practice-management-software%3F_bt%3D42684442540%26_bk%3D%252Bmy%2520%252Bcase%26_bm%3Db"}],"Device":{"BrowserInfo":{"Name":"Chrome","Version":"30.0"},"PlatformInfo":{"Name":"Android","Version":"4.4"}},"IPInfo":null}],"Cookies":[""],"Hosts":null}]';
var parsed = JSON.parse("{ \"data\": " + rawData + " }").data;
console.log(parsed);
```

Comment: @James The result is still an array, as it is an exact parse of the original string. You need to do `alert(myData[0].BusinessId)`.